# How to compute two custom fields in sale order line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, odoo-10, odoo

I added two new costume fields in sale order line (Height & Width) and a field called total area. I wanna compute the two fields (Height & Width) in total area field

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your code. Please take the tour and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in `sale_order_line` classe

```
@api.depends('height', 'width')
def _get_area(self):
    for line in self:
        line.area = line.height * line.width 


height = fields.Integer(string='Height')
width = fields.Integer(string='Width')
area = fields.Integer(compute='_get_area', string='Area article', readonly=True, store=True)
```